# Test $\beta_{0}$ = 0 (the regression line crosses the original point) in a simple linear regression. How do we calculate $\beta_{0}$'s variance?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

If we test $\beta_{1}$ = 0, var($\beta_{0}$) has a term 1/n in denominator. Is var($\beta_{0}$) different when we test $\beta_{0}$ = 0?

Comment: (1) In ordinary regression $\beta_0$ is a fixed but unknown quantity; it has variance 0. Presumably you're asking about the variance of the *estimate*, $\hat{\beta}_0$, which is a sample quantity, a function of the data (and the observations, being a random variable, do have a variance). $\quad$  (2) Your question is unclear. For example (though this isn't the only issue), you talk about $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$; were either of those meant to be the other there, or are you discussing an issue involving both? ... please try to clarify your question.

Comment: Why only the partial edit? At the start you're testing $\beta_1$ and at the end you're testing $\beta_0$. $\quad$ Did you still mean to leave the hat off? (If not, `$\hat{\beta}_0$` gets you the hat). Please address both issues, carefully. $\quad$ What has the fact that you may have tested one to do with the variance of the other? The fitted model is still the fitted model --- you don't indicate any change in your model, nor even any conclusion from the test.